# Windows Enterprise PIN login prevents using AD password later

Tags: windows, active-directory, enterprise, dataflex

I have code to login to AD that fails on Windows 10 Enterprise when the user has used a PIN, rather than an AD password, to sign onto Windows. Works everywhere else, including in VMs running on that box.

How can I tell if a Windows Hello PIN was used so I can warn the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn’t find anything that develops to warn user for not to use PIN.

As a workaround I would suggest you to Reset the PIN or Remove PIN password on Windows 10 Enterprise.
Steps is mentioned Below.

1. Open Settings on Windows 10.
2. Click on Accounts.
3. Click on Sign-in options.
4. Under the “Manage how your sign into your device” section, select the Windows Hello PIN option. ...
5. Click the Remove button.
6. Click the Remove button again. ...
7. Confirm the current password.
8. Click the OK button.

Comment: thanks for that. Further testing showed the issue wasn't consistent. For the time being I'm going to pop up a warning on Enterprise to say it *might* happen. Something else obviously involved but too few enterprise users to put much effort into this right now. Thanks again.